# R: Getting data from list

Tags: r

I have the following simplified example:

```
list1 <- list(Value1=c('9','6','5','5'),Value2=c('4','3'))
list2<-list(Value1=c('9','2','3','5'),Value2=c('4','8'))
TotalList <- list()
TotalList[['time1']] <- list1
TotalList[['time2']] <- list2
```

How can i get the following `TotalList[1:2]$Value1` (pseudocode) which is to get all `Value1` from both `time1` and `time2`?

Comment: Try `lapply` i.e. `lapply(TotalList, "[[",1)` or if you need to get by the names, `lapply(TotalList, function(x) x[names(x)=='Value1'])`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It gives the desired output. But is there a way to get it with using the `Value1`? My data is not distributed uniformly, so getting the 1st list from every list will not give `Value1` from every list?

Comment: Have you tried the second option

Comment: Yes its working.Thank you.Add it as an answer if you want to accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
lapply(TotalList, function(x) x[names(x)=='Value1'])
```